# Why this CSS3 transition is not working when I unfocus an input? (:focus)

Tags: css, css-transitions

This is my CSS:

```
.light .contact_form_widget input:focus,.light .contact_form_widget textarea:focus,.light #commentform input:focus,.light #commentform textarea:focus,.light #contactform input:focus,.light #contactform textarea:focus{
transition:all .2s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition:all .2s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition:all .2s ease-in-out;
-o-transition:all .2s ease-in-out;
-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden
}
```

Why this CSS transition is not working when I unfocus an input or a textarea? The transition works on links, image-hover-overlays...

[I removed the link, not needed for the question, it was only an example].

**EDIT:** This is the other part of the CSS (I didn't post it before, I don't know why, probably it was too obvious):

```
.light .contact_form_widget input:focus,.light .contact_form_widget textarea:focus,.light #commentform input:focus,.light #commentform textarea:focus,.light #contactform input:focus,.light #contactform textarea:focus{
background:#FFF;border:1px solid #BBB;
box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.13);
-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.13);
-moz-box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.13)
}
```

Comment: You have only defined for it to transition when the element is in `:focus`. Without that focus, there is no `transition` property set.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try like this **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8g6g4/1/)**

**CSS:**

```
input[type=text]{
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all .2s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all .2s ease-out;
    transition: all .2s ease-out
}

input[type=text]:focus {
    border-color: #777;
    color: #000;
    background: #fff;
    outline: 0
}
```

You need to give animation for normal state instead on focus

Comment: Awesome, yes, it works perfect. (I don't know where I had my head, lol :p). Btw, let me ask: is it right if I use the same code without `[type=text]`? Thank you.